# Socket exception when trying to connect to server database in java

Tags: java, sockets, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a MySQL db from my Windows application using `jdbc`. But it is showing socket a exception. I changed the connection string to ipaddress also but it didn't work. Can anybody please help me in this regard?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may receive this error when a thread tries to open a socket to some port number to get connection but could not able to connect.

First, check the datasource used to connect to DB.

Ping for the host,

Telnet:

```
   telnet hostname  portnumber
```

To check port is ready to accept the connection or not by doing a

```
   netstat -an | find “portnumber” or netstat -an | grep “portnumber”
```

it should be in LISTENING state.Incase it’s not in listening state restart the service to reset.

Firewall
   Make sure Firewall on from host and To host both are allowing connections. Make sure you dont have any rules setup in firewall which blocks incoming connections to the host or outgoing connections to host.

Comment: The only part of this that is relevant is the last part. If the port is accessible via the firewall but not listening you will get a different exception: 'connection refused'.

Answer (score 0):

this is most likely caused by a network issue between your machine and your db server, or that your configuration (port?) is incorrect, or that your db is not started.

Answer (score 0):

**-** First start with the basic diagnosis of the connection using `Ping` utility.

**-** If you are able to ping or if you can't ping , in either case please check is there a `firewall` that is blocking the connection, if yes add an exception on the Firewall on the server side for that port or your application.

**-** The above problem stated by you points to the problem during the very initial stage of connection.

**-** Please also see that you are connecting to the correct IP, if its a Server on the Net, then i am assuming that server has a `Static Public IP`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data source connection string and fire wall, if you used third party firewall disable and try